# Convert SQL to linq expression with count

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert the following SQL into a LINQ expression

```
SELECT    COUNT(ID) AS Count, MyCode
FROM      dbo.Archive
WHERE     DateSent>=@DateStartMonth AND DateSent<=@DateEndMonth
GROUP BY  MyCode
```

and I have been trying to follow this webpage as an example:
[Converting SQL containing top, count, group and order to LINQ (2 Entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606124/converting-sql-containing-top-count-group-and-order-to-linq-2-entities)

I got this so far but I am stuck on understanding the new part

```
var res = (from p in db.Archives
           where (p.DateSent>= dateStartMonth) && (p.DateSent< dateToday)
           group p by p.MyCode into g
           select new { ??????MyCode = g.something?, MonthlyCount= g.Count() });
```

Thanks in advance for helping

**UPDATE:**
can you explain what g.Key is? I dont understand where that variable came from or what it is referring too? I mean what if I group on 4 different things? How would I refer to each one?

```
var res = from archive in db.Archives
      where archive.DateSent >= dateStartMonth &&
            archive.DateSent < dateToday
      group archive by archive.MyCode, archive.Extra into archiveGrp
      select new 
      { 
           MyCode = archiveGrp.Key, 
           Extra = archiveGrp.???
           MonthlyCount = archiveGrp.Count() 
      };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LINQ statement below should work:

```
var res = from archive in db.Archives
          where archive.DateSent >= dateStartMonth &&
                archive.DateSent < dateToday
          group archive by archive.MyCode into archiveGrp
          select new 
          { 
               MyCode = archiveGrp.Key, 
               MonthlyCount = archiveGrp.Count() 
          };
```

Notice that the [Key property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343251.aspx) will contain the value of the property that you group on, in this case MyCode.

Answer (score 0):

```
from p in archive
where p.DateSent >= dateStartMonth && p.DateSent < dateToday
group p by p.MyCode into g
select new { Count = g.Count(), MyCode = g.Key  }
```

produces the same output as your Sql in Linqpad