# Convert Sql query to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Select Top(8) * from products order by CreatedOn desc can u convert this query to Linq List
where product is a table in sql Created on is a dateTime comumn..

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = (from p in products
             orderby p.CreatedOn descending
             select p).Take(8);
```

OR

```
var result = products.OrderByDescending(p=>p.CreatedOn).Take(8);
```

Comment: @Marko Ivanovski @Timwi - sorry a typo, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Linq to Sql Cheat Sheet](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/08/12/linq-to-sql-cheat-sheet). It contains a lot of useful, easy to follow LinqToSql information and is available for C# and VB.NET.

Relating to your query, look at the Paging and Order section, taking out the Skip(x) part of the query, and and replace the .Take(5) with your .Take(8) for your Top(8) value.

Answer (score -1):

Check this StackOverflow question which talks about converting similar kind of query:

[Converting SQL containing top, count, group and order to LINQ (2 Entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606124/converting-sql-containing-top-count-group-and-order-to-linq-2-entities)

Comment: @Timwi - Thanks. Did not realize it was a duplicate from stack overflow itself.