# Simple LINQ question in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to use `LINQ` to return the an element which occurs maximum number of times AND the number of times it occurs.

For example:
I have an array of strings:

```
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry", "cherry", "cherry", "blueberry" };

//...
Some LINQ statement here
//...
```

In this array, the query would return `cherry` as the maximum occurred element, and `3` as the number of times it occurred. I would also be willing to split them into two queries if that is necessary (*i.e.,* first query to get the `cherry`, and second to return the count of `3`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var topWordGroup = words.GroupBy(word => word).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
// topWordGroup might be a null!
string topWord = topWordGroup.Key;
int topWordCount = topWordGroup.Count;
```

And in case if we don't like `O(N log N)`:

```
var topWordGroup = words.GroupBy(word => word).Aggregate((current, acc) => current.Count() < acc.Count() ? acc : current);
```

Comment: This is `O(n log n)` when `O(n)` is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c/4888703#4888703.

Answer (score 12):

The solutions presented so far are `O(n log n)`. Here's an `O(n)` solution:

```
var max = words.GroupBy(w => w)
               .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
               .MaxBy(g => g.Count);
Console.WriteLine(
    "The most frequent word is {0}, and its frequency is {1}.",
    max.Word,
    max.Count
);
```

This needs a definition of `MaxBy`. Here is one:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IComparable> projectionToComparable
) {
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (!e.MoveNext()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence is empty.");
        }
        TSource max = e.Current;
        IComparable maxProjection = projectionToComparable(e.Current);
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            IComparable currentProjection = projectionToComparable(e.Current);
            if (currentProjection.CompareTo(maxProjection) > 0) {
                max = e.Current;
                maxProjection = currentProjection;
            }
        }
        return max;                
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also substitute `Aggregate` for `MaxBy` if necessary, although `MaxBy` is *much* nicer: `var max = words.GroupBy(x => x, (k, g) => new { Word = k, Count = g.Count() }).Aggregate((a, x) => (x.Count > a.Count) ? x : a);`

Comment: Guys! GroupBy isn't linear. There is small penalty for hashing collisions. I am making this up but it's something like O(n * log log n)

Comment: @Jakub Šturc: And sort can degrade to `O(n^2)` in the worst case depending on the algorithm used. But on average, it's `O(n log n)`. `GroupBy` is usually going to be `O(n)`.

Answer (score 4):

First thing that comes to mind (meaning there is probably a more efficient way)

```
var item = words.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).First()
//item.Key is "cherry", item.Count() is 3
```

**EDIT**: forgot op wanted the name **and** the count

Comment: This is `O(n log n) when `O(n)` is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c/4888703#4888703.

Comment: @Jason Ha! We meet again! And once again you are correct.  I had overlooked using Jon Skeet's MoreLinq

Comment: What's Jon's MoreLinq? I've seen his MiscUtil, but never MoreLinq.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/   And for the list of the added methods: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview  MaxBy is one of them.

Comment: Heh, just read the source for his `MaxBy`. I feel pretty good in coming up with effectively the same implementation (and same name!) as Jon. I think I'm calling it quits for the day; nowhere to go but down from here. Thanks for the linq (ha, puns are not funny).

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry", "cherry", "cherry", "blueberry" };

var topWordAndCount=words
    .GroupBy(w=>w)
    .OrderByDescending(g=>g.Count())
    .Select(g=>new {Word=g.Key,Count=g.Count()})
    .FirstOrDefault();

//if(topWordAndCount!=null)
//{
//    topWordAndCount.Word
//    topWordAndCount.Count
```

Comment: This is `O(n log n)` when `O(n)` is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c/4888703#4888703.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

[Converting SQL containing top, count, group and order to LINQ (2 Entities)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606124/converting-sql-containing-top-count-group-and-order-to-linq-2-entities)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry", "cherry", "cherry", "blueberry" };

var r = words.GroupBy (x => x)
             .OrderByDescending (g => g.Count ())
             .FirstOrDefault ();
Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("The element {0} occurs {1} times.", r.Key, r.Count ()));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler O(n) solution:

```
var groups = words.GroupBy(x => x);
var max = groups.Max(x => x.Count());
var top = groups.First(y => y.Count() == max).Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very fast O(n) solution in one line(!):

```
s.GroupBy(x => x).Aggregate((IGrouping<string,string>)null, (x, y) =>  (x != null && y != null && x.Count() >= y.Count()) || y == null ? x : y, x => x);
```

Or this:

```
s.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }).Aggregate(new { Key = "", Count = 0 }, (x, y) => x.Count >= y.Count ? x : y, x => x);
```