# Linq select records closest to date

Tags: c#, linq

How do you use Linq to select the record that is closest to a specified date?  This is for a transaction table that has a date, product id, location id, and balance.

Given these requirements:

- Select the last transaction of the day if there were several on the specified day
- Select the closest prior transaction if there were none on the specified day
- Show the balance in multiple locations (eg warehouses) - each warehouse will have separate transactions
- Show the balance for multiple products - each product will have separate transactions

Table data:

```
// code
Id, TransDateTime,    ProductId, WarehouseId, Balance
1,  1-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           100
2,  1-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         2,           10
3,  2-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           150
4,  3-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         2,           25
5,  3-Jan-2011 00:00, 2,         1,           333
6,  7-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           149
7,  7-Jan-2011 01:00, 1,         2,           30
8,  7-Jan-2011 02:00, 1,         2,           35
```

Test dates and outputs

```
Date: 1-Jan would output:
1,  1-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           100
2,  1-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         2,           10

Date: 3-Jan would output:
3,  2-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           150 
4,  3-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         2,           25
5,  3-Jan-2011 00:00, 2,         1,           333
// product 1, warehouse 1 wasn't sold on the 3rd
// so the row from 2-Jan is returned

Date: 7-Jan would output:
5,  3-Jan-2011 00:00, 2,         1,           333
6,  7-Jan-2011 00:00, 1,         1,           149
9,  7-Jan-2011 02:00, 1,         2,           35
// product 2, warehouse 1 wasn't sold on the 7th
// so the row from 3-Jan is returned
// product 1, warehouse 2 was sold twice on the 7th
// so the later one is used
```

I think it's going to require grouping of groups (product -> warehouse -> date) or similar.  Its beyond my linq ability!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps:
1) Filter out transactions that happened after `inputDate`
2) Group rest of transactions by product and warehouse
3) In each group find most recent transaction
4) Format result object

Straightforward implementation:

```
DateTime inputDate = ...;
var result = transactions
          .Where(t => t.TransDateTime.Date <= inputDate.Date)
          .GroupBy(t => new {t.ProductId, t.WarehouseId})
          .Select(x => new {
               x.Key,
               LastTransaction = x.OrderByDescending(t => t.TransDateTime).First(),
          })
          .Select(x => new {
               Id = x.LastTransaction.Id,
               Date = x.LastTransaction.TransDateTime,
               ProductId = x.Key.ProductId,
               WarehouseId = x.Key.WarehouseId,
               Balance = x.LastTransaction.Balance,
          });
```

If you want some optimizations you can consider implementing `MaxBy` extension method for `IEnumerable` to replace `x.OrderByDescending(t => t.TransDateTime).First()`. It will improve performance if you have many transactions since it is `O(n)` instead of `O(n log n)`. `MaxBy` implementation can be taken here for example: [Simple LINQ question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c/4888703#4888703)

Comment: +1 Seems to work so far thanks, just one error that was easily fixed: `The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.`

Comment: @JK, it is linq-to-sql specifics, i was testing on linq-to-objects.