# C# Linq question GROUP BY?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection `List<CustomClass>` which I am trying to find a way to return a field which corresponds to another field that occurs the highest number of times. 
I've asked a similar question in the past, but I'm not sure how to extend the logic to a custom class.
For instance.

My `CustomClass` has three public properties:

```
Title
Mid
Eid
```

And a `List<CustomClass> MatchedFeatures = List<CustomClass>();` is populated in a loop.

I need to perform a Linq operation to return the `Mid` of the class that has the largest number of occurring identical `Eid`'s. So we are counting the identical `Eid` columns.

I have tried using

```
var TopResult = MatchedFeatures.GroupBy(MatchedFeature => MatchedFeature).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it doesn't return what I am looking for.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I am using C#

Here is the previous asked question, which seems to work fine. Now how to extend it in this case...?
[Simple LINQ question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c)

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to group those features where the `Eid` property is the same, you should use `GroupBy(MatchedFeature => MatchedFeature.Eid)`.

If you leave out the `.Eid` it will only group those features together which are entirely the same - not the ones that have the same `Eid`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `MatchedFeature => MatchedFeature.Eid` instead of `MatchedFeature => MatchedFeature`  which is an instance of your Custom class hense you get one group per instance of your custom class I believe.