# Use LINQ to find MAX or MIN of a field from all child records

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Please review my brief example code below and tell me if there is better, tighter way to write the LINQ query.  The parent class is simply a student's name and a list of test score data.  The child class is a single test score datum.  I want to find the worst (or best) score out of all of the TestScore values and then identify the student who had the best score.

Thanks!

```vb
Dim query = From s In studentList _
            Where s.ScoreList.Select(Function(d) d.TestScore).Min _
                = studentList.SelectMany(Function(g) g.ScoreList).Select(Function(h) h.TestScore).Min _
            Select StudentName = s.Student, _
                   WorstScore = s.ScoreList.Select(Function(g) g.TestScore).Min
```

Comment: Seeing this long VB.NET code makes me sick :/

Comment: You really didn't need all that boilerplate code in there. The query itself makes it pretty easy to infer what we need to know about your classes.

Comment: OT: Does anyone but me think that the phrase "LINQ Query" is redundant?  But I can't think of a better way to say it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a VB person so there may be some syntax errors, but I can suggest two improvements:

- Rather than using Select then Min, use the overload of Min which accepts a projection
- Don't find the overall minimum on every iteration; just do it once:

  ```
  Dim worstScore = studentList.SelectMany(Function(g) g.ScoreList) _
                              .Min(Function(h) h.TestScore)

  Dim query = From s In studentList _
              Where s.ScoreList.Min(Function(d) d.TestScore) = worstScore
              Select s.Student
  ```

Note that I've removed the anonymous type from the query - we know the `worstScore` already, so we don't really need it in with the query result. Note that there could still be multiple students *with* that worst score though.

Comment: I prefer your answer because it removes the redundant data (worstScore) from the query.  Thanks for pointing out the Min projection.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Dim query = studentList.OrderBy(Function(d) d.ScoreList.Select(Function(d) d.TestScore).Min).First()
```

Using `OrderByDescending` and `Max` to find the best score.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It is pretty minimalistic, which is what I originally was seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do if I were you is add a `MinimumScore` and `MaximumScore` property to `StudentScores` make `AddScore` keep track of the minimum and maximum score that you've seen so far. Now for a given student you can find these in `O(1)` time instead of in `O(n)` time

Then what you want to do is write an implementation of `MaxBy` and `MinBy`. I don't speak VB fluently, but you can find an implementation of `MaxBy` in C# in a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888537/simple-linq-question-in-c/4888703#4888703) and convert to VB accordingly.

Finally, having done all this, you can say

```
studentWithBestScore = studentList.MaxBy(s => s.MaximumScore);
var bestScore = studentWithBestScore.MaximumScore;
```

(Again, you'll have to convert this to VB.)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond.  The MaxBy and MinBy might be useful to me at another time.  For now, I'll pursue an approach that uses native LINQ syntax.