# Majority vote from string[] using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to use **Linq in C#** to find the majority of elements in an array?  To make it a bit more complicated, if there is no majority, it should take the first element.

So for example with the array `["A", "B", "B"]`, the statement should evaluate to `"B"`.
And, with the array `["A", "B", "C"]`, the statement should evaluate to `"A"`.

I'm sure there are a 100 other ways to do this, but curious if there is a Linq solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string majority = yourArray.GroupBy(x => x)
                           .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                           .First()
                           .Key;
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/w0xKy)

Comment: This is `O(n log n)`. You can do better (avoid sorting).

Comment: If there is no majority (count is equal for all) I don't think `OrderByDescending` is guaranteed to return the first item from the original list.

Comment: @Magnus: Why do you think that? From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx): "This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved."

Comment: Indeed, for equal number of strings, fails.

Answer (score 6):

```
var majority = array.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .MaxBy(g => g.Count())
                    .Key;
```

Here, I'm using [`MaxBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888703/45914) (follow the link to a version of it, but the idea is simple), which you can define as an extension method.

Comment: There's a link to a version of it on another answer. Follow the link.

Comment: @Dave Bish: You're joking, right? Finding the max of a sequence is trivial.

Comment: Adding an extension method, that does the same thing as GroupBy().First() ?!

Comment: @DaveBish: It's not the same - it gives the same result, but it's more efficient.

Comment: @Dave Bish: It's not the same thing at all! It's semantically different, and it's more efficient! First off, `GroupBy.First` is wrong, you need `GroupBy.OrderByDescending.First`. Second, `GroupBy.OrderByDescending.First` sorts the list which is `O(n log n)`. You don't need the sorted list, you just need the maximum which is `O(n)`. So, don't sort the list, just find the maximum. That's what `MaxBy` does. It's not the same thing at all, and it's really simple.

Comment: @DaveBish Did you mean OrderBy().First() instead of GroupBy().First() in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = new List<string>{"A", "B", "B"};

var mostCommonOrFirst = strings
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .First();
```

Comment: this fails too for equals