# Majority vote over strings that FAILS when equal

Tags: c#, linq

Inspired from this
[Majority vote from string[] using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539438/majority-vote-from-string-using-linq)

I'm trying to do a majority vote over strings like this

```
var ips = new List<string>();

ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
ips.Add("10.10.10.2");

ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
ips.Add("192.168.0.1");

string majority = ips.GroupBy(s => s)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .First();
```

However, if strings are equal as number (see above) I'd like to return FALSE
instead of first item.

Basically for me this is a uncertain state :)

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Go as far as `OrderByDescending`, then take the first 2 items. Look at the `Count()` for both, and see whether they're equal.

Comment: Do you mean the string "FALSE" or the boolean `false`? The former is doable, the latter not so much as its not compatible with the type of `Key` which is a string..

Comment: no, no, just detect if equals which in my case is wrong

Comment: I think by 'equals', OP is saying when there is no majority aka all/both options have the same number of votes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's find out **2** top votes, and have a look if we have a *tie*:

```
var data = ips
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .Select(chunk => new {
     value = chunk.Key,
     count = chunk.Count() 
   })
  .OrderByDescending(item => item.count)
  .Take(2)
  .ToArray();

string majority = (data.Length == 0) || 
                  (data.Length == 2) && (data[0].count == data[1].count)
  ? "No majority"
  : data[0].value;
```

Comment: @Jamiec: Sorry, but I return `No majority` in `2` cases: if we don't have any data (`data.Length == 0`) or if we have `2` *diffrent* string with same `count`: `(data.Length == 0) || 
(data.Length == 2) && (data[0].count == data[1].count)`. If `data.Length == 1`, `data[0].value` will be returned

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a fairly simple extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TResult FirstIfUniqueCount<TKey,TElement,TResult>(this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>> items, Func<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>,TResult> selector)
    {
        if(!items.Any())
            return default(TResult);
        if(items.Count() < 2)
            return selector(items.First());

        var firstTwoItems = items.Take(2).ToArray();
        if(firstTwoItems[0].Count() == firstTwoItems[1].Count())
            return default(TResult);
        return selector(firstTwoItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string majority = ips.GroupBy(s => s)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .FirstIfUniqueCount(g => g.Key);
```

This would return `default(string)` if there is no majority (so, `null` when selecting a string such as `Key`).

Live example: https://rextester.com/JHFG46105 (uncomment one line to make no majority)

Answer (score 0):

Check the count of the first grouped element of the ordered enumerable whether is it equal to the rest, if so then return the string `False` else get the first highest occuring one.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ips = new List<string>();

    ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
    ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
    ips.Add("10.10.10.2");
    ips.Add("10.10.10.2");

    ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
    ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
    ips.Add("192.168.0.1");
    ips.Add("192.168.0.1");

    var groupedItems = ips
        .GroupBy(s => s)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Key = x.Key,
            Count = x.Count()
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

    string result = groupedItems.All(x => groupedItems.ElementAt(0).Count == x.Count) ? "False" 
                        : groupedItems.FirstOrDefault().Key;
}
```